# Populating RadComboBox using for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

Hi I have RadComboBox where I am trying to populate the dropdown options using for loop...

```
 int last=20;
 int lastitem;
 for (int i=1; i < last; i++)
                {
                    lastitem = i + 1;
                    categoriesCombo.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(i.ToString()+ "-"+lastitem.ToString()));
                }
```

Problem with this code is that it only displays one value the first one. Please let me know how to fix it so it can populate all the items in drop down in for loop. Thanks

Comment: Use a debugger, It seems unlikely that the issue could exist in your code.

Comment: Your posted code is fine. Where you have this code block (I mean is it in page_load event)

Comment: Yes in page load event

Comment: You will have to post more code. cause this posted code block is definitely not causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your code but not able to reproduce your issue.

Please check my code snippet.

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="categoriesCombo" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASPX.CS

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int last = 20;
        int lastitem;
        for (int i = 1; i < last; i++)
        {
            lastitem = i + 1;
            categoriesCombo.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(i.ToString() + "-" + lastitem.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

OutPut:

[image]

Let me if any concern.